# SQL pairing adjacent rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using postgreSQL (latest). I'm a total noob.

I have a view that always gives me a table of an even number of rows- no duplicates (the letters are analogous to unique keys) and no nulls, let's call it letter_view:

```
|   letter    |
|-------------|
|      A      |
|      B      |
|      C      |
|      D      |
|      E      |
|      F      |
|      G      |
|      H      |
```

My view already uses an `ORDER BY` clause so the table is pre-sorted.

What I'm trying to do is merge every two rows into a single row
with each value from those two rows. So for n rows, I need the result set to have
n / 2 rows with combined adjacent rows.

```
| l1    |  l2  |
|-------|------|
| A     | B    | 
| C     | D    | 
| E     | F    | 
| G     | H    |
```

I've tried using `lead` and I think I'm close but I can't quite get it in the format I need.

My best query attempt looks like this:

`SELECT letter AS letter_1, lead(letter, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY 2) AS letter_2 from letter_view;`

but I get:

```
 letter_1 | letter_2
----------+----------
        A |       B
        B |       C   <--- Don't need this
        C |       D
        D |       E   <--- Don't need this
        E |       F
        F |       G   <--- Don't need this
        G |       H 
        H |           <--- Don't need this
 (8 rows)
```

I checked several other answers on SO, and looked through
the PostgreSQL docs and w3C SQL tutorials but I can't find a succinct answer.

What is this technique called and how would I do it?

I'm trying to do this in pure SQL if possible.

I know I could use multiple queries with LIMIT and OFFSET to get the data with multiple selects or potentially by using a cursor but that seems very inefficient for large input sets although I could be totally wrong. Again, total noob.

Any help in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` to get the next value . . . but you need a way to filter as well.  I would suggest `row_number()`:

```
select letter_1, letter_2
from (select letter AS letter_1,
             lead(letter, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY 2 order by ??) AS letter_2, 
             row_number() over (partition by 2 order by ??) as seqnum
      from letter_view
     ) lv
where seqnum % 2 = 1;
```

Notes:

- I included the partition clause as you have in the original code.  I don't know what "2" refers to.
- You should be explicit about the `order by`.  It is not wise to depend on the ordering of some underlying table or view.

Comment: The `partition by 2` was me trying to get it to subdivide into groups of two, but I realize now that if I change that value it does not change the results. Not sure how to correctly use `partition by `

Comment: @user7015381 . . . You use `partition by` if you want to break the data into different groups -- say if you had a "source" column and wanted to do this for each `source`.